# How do I make a very wide HTML table narrow, such that it fits the screen width?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `HTML` table with multiple columns:

```
<table id="req_header" border="2" style="overflow: auto;">
    <tr>
        <th><i class="fa fa-solid fa-check"></i></th>
        <th>Actual amount</th>
        <th>Current reading</th>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>Expected amount</th>
        <th>Installment</th>
        <th>Meter current date</th>
        <th>Meter previous date</th>
        <th>Previous reading</th>
        <th>Start from</th>
        <th>Total charge</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Unit consumed</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am creating the rows dynamically and populating the cell values like this:

```
for(let data in snapshot){
    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(7);
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(8);
    var cell9 = row.insertCell(9);
    var cell10 = row.insertCell(10);
    var cell11 = row.insertCell(11);
    var cell12 = row.insertCell(12);

    var input=document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    input.style.textAlign="center";
    cell.appendChild(input);

    var input=document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.style.textAlign="center";
    input.value = snapshot[data]["index"];
    cell1.appendChild(input);

    /* and so on, I am populating my table */
}
```

When I execute the code, my table shows like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3bJI.png)

As you can see the table crosses the screen width, as a result only half of the table is visible. Is there a way to reduce the table width, so that it fits the screen width? I cannot remove any of the columns, as all of them are important.

Comment: Try [Bootstrap's Responsive tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a horizontal scrollbar to avoid this problem. Wrap the table in a div tag and set it's overflow property to scroll like this.

```
.table-wrapper {
     overflow: scroll;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update with CSS from the comments:

```
td { 
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

For mobile phones I leave the table width but assign an additional CSS class to the table to enable horizontal scrolling (table will not go over the mobile screen anymore):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* horizontal scrollbar for tables if mobile screen */
    .tablemobile {
        overflow-x: auto;
        display: block;
    }
}
```